# Javascript: object[method]() not working or how to build a jQuery plugin for a plain Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I need help making a jQuery plugin for one of my vanilla JS scripts, [this here](https://github.com/thednp/kute.js/blob/master/dist/kute.jquery.js) is the current jQuery plugin, but the next version works with more methods and I need to address them all somehow.

Currently I was working on this

```
(function($) {
    var t;  
    $.fn.KUTE = function( method, start, end, ops ) { // method can be Animate(), fromTo(), to(), stop(), start(), chain(), pause(), stop(), etc
        return this.each(function(){        
            if ( method === 'to' ) {                
                t = new KUTE[method]( this, null, end, ops );
            } else if ( method === 'fromTo' || method === 'Animate' ) {
                t = new KUTE[method]( this, start, end, ops );
            } 
            if ( t !== undefined && typeof t[method] === 'function' ) {
                console.log(t) // this shows proper object
                t[method]() // this doesn't work
            }   
        });
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

Why `t[method]()` doesn't work and how can I make it work?

UPDATE: I am adding here some sample code on how things work around this code. Basically I build a tween object

```
var tween = $(div).KUTE('to', { left: tl }, { easing: easing, duration: 1000 } );
```

Then I need to `start()` it, `stop()` it and other methods.

```
$(tween).KUTE('start'); // this should basically be it.
```

Now, I've been reading about some Javascript stuff like `call()` and `apply()` and I was kinda thinking this may be required in order to work, but even so the `t[method].call(t) // where t is "this"`, doesn't work. I hope I've put it right to indicate my problem, please correct me if anything wrong.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the issue, but you are missing some semicolons around the problem line. Try fixing those.

Comment: @Katana314 While I'm pretty anti-ASI, there's nothing on those lines that should cause a failure.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work?" What error do you get?

Comment: @ssube instead of triggering the function as expected, it doesn't do anything as expected. In plain JS `t.start()` would go with the animation but not with this jQuery setup.

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(t)`?

Comment: Shows proper object, as I said in the question: `KUTE.Tween {_el: div.line.line-0, _dr: 1000, _r: 20, _vSR: Object, _vS: null…}`

Comment: If you see `console.log(t)`, but no error after that, then unless something is catching an error, then I think that could mean the function is being called, but maybe just doesn't do what you expect. Try inserting a `debugger;` line before that line, and then step into it via the browser's debugger.

Comment: @Katana314 thanks so much for your input, I didn't know this practice, it can actually show errors while parsing the code. Unfortunately it's not helping me make that function execute when I need it. I will update the question with more info, thanks again and stay close.

Comment: Breakpoint on `t[method]()` in the browser's developer tools and simply see what's going on. You'll have your answer instantly.

Comment: Can you post the source for the `KUTE` object?

Comment: This here is an older version.
https://github.com/thednp/kute.js/blob/master/kute.full.js

Comment: Can it be that the method doesn't work because you run them in different context so they miss "this" of jQuery ? Try to use .bind() when passing the method

Comment: Are you using the code from link you've posted? If so, how are you going to create an instance of `object`. You can create instances only on `function` types.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `return` is an instance of `this`, instead it should be an instance of `Tween` for `this`, where `this` is the DOM object, and thus the `t[method]()` will never work unless I do something without `return this.each(function(){)` and even so, not going to work, I tried many times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found out why, my last comment above explains it and I made a different jQuery function.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.KUTE = function( method, start, end, ops ) { // method can be Animate(), fromTo(), to(), stop(), start(), chain(), pause() 
        var tws = [], i, l = this.length;

        for (i=0;i<l;i++){
            var mt = this[i][method];
            if ( typeof mt === 'function' ) {
                mt.apply(this[i]);
            }    
            if ( method === 'to' ) {
                tws.push( new KUTE[method]( this[i], start, end ) ); // here start is end and end is ops 
            } else if ( method === 'fromTo' || method === 'Animate' ) {
                tws.push( new KUTE[method]( this[i], start, end, ops ) ); 
            }           
        }
        return tws;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Next to do is, that if `this.length > 1` do a nice little `FOR()` instead of the super bad and ugly `jQuery.each()`.

Issue solved, see my [codepen](http://codepen.io/thednp/pen/vOvVPq) for an example.

UPDATE: I also added the `FOR` and it works as expected. I updated the answer above.